# Set date to specific date in Java every month and week

Tags: java

Im working on a project that visually displays statistical data from each month and week and i dont know how to elegantly renew the dates of each week and month.

For example, i want to display this months data. I have to make two date variables in Java. The first one being 1.5.2021 and the second one being todays date. I dont know how to elegantly set the first variable to 1.x.xxxx without making a string out of the current date first and then cuting it, doing some numerics with it and merging it back together to 1.5.2021.

Same goes for weekly statistics where i need the Monday date and the Sunday date, for example today being Monday 10.5.2021 and the end on 17.5.2021.

So my idea is to get current date to string format, slice it, convert it to int, calculate the desired dates and the put it back to string(no need to go back to datetype since its gonna be used for querying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should definitely take a look at the classes within the `java.time` package.

In your case, your current date could be a `LocalDate` instance, for example with the following line:

```java
LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 1);
```

And then you could just use the `withDayOfMonth` method to get a new `LocalDate` instance with the day of the month set to 1:

```java
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate firstOfMonth = currentDate.withDayOfMonth(1);
```

Comment: Yes i can use this for the month part. I'll check java.time package if similar thing can be done to get the mondays date of the current week.

Comment: @Kalybor Well, this can be done with a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), which is able to convert some temporal to another one based on some logic. The [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) helper class contains a set of methods with commonly used adjustments, such as finding the Monday before the current date. Something like `currentDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` would do the trick.

Comment: If your week goes from Monday to Sunday always (you don’t need to take into account that the week may start on Sunday or some other day of the week), then just `currentDate.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)` and similarly for Sunday.

Comment: Thank you very much, both replies are valid. Worked wonderful.